# PI4 Won't boot green led flashes 3 long 3 short I2C error

Tags: pi-4, i2c

Everything was fine with my pi4 until yesterday that didn't boot. I checked the led lights and gives me 3 long and 3 short flashes.  I checked in the docs https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#led-warning-flash-codes and i found that's a I2C Error.

This error comes even without sd card

I tried reflashing the sd, cleaning the pi, changing the power source and outlets but i don't know how could i fix the issue due not finding info about this error on internet.

Can you guys help me point the direction to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware that is a permanent error.  There is no fix.

You will need to negotiate a replacement for the Pi.

Comment: How and where could i negotiate?

Comment: From the seller.

Comment: I doubt you can "negotiate" a replacement for a pi that worked "until yesterday" - buy a new pi